# Trying to install Flask-User getting the following error

Tags: flask, flask-user

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement Flask-User (from versions: 0.3, 0.3.1, 0.3.2, 0.3.3, 0.3.4, 0.3.5, 0.3.6, 0.3.7, 0.3.8, 0.4.0, 0.4.1, 0.4.2, 0.4.3, 0.4.4, 0.4.5, 0.4.6, 0.4.7, 0.4.8, 0.4.9, 0.5.0, 0.5.1, 0.5.2, 0.5.3, 0.5.4, 0.5.5, 0.6, 0.6.1, 0.6.2, 0.6.3, 0.6.4, 0.6.5, 0.6.6, 0.6.7, 0.6.8, 0.6.9, 0.6.10, 0.6.12, 0.6.13, 0.6.14, 0.6.15, 0.6.16, 0.6.17, 0.6.19, 0.6.20, 0.6.21, 1.0.1.1, 1.0.1.2, 1.0.1.3, 1.0.1.4, 1.0.1.5, 1.0.2.0, 1.0.2.1, 1.0.2.2)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for Flask-User
```

Comment: There are several packages on PyPi (https://pypi.org/) that sort of match Flask-User, and a few of them look like they've been untouched for a while. Which are you trying to use?

Comment: I do not kwon anything about pipit. I am not using it.

Comment: `pip install` is backed up by the Python Package Index

Comment: I am using python 3.8.9. On the webpage of flask-user is the information that its tested with python 3.8. Maybe that's the problem. I am trying right to downgrade python but it seems it is not that easy.

Comment: Okay, I think I understand what you mean. I habe the newest pip version.

Comment: Flask-Login is a well-known alternative. You might consider looking at that.

Comment: Okay, I'll get along with it. Thank you.